# Splitting the string array into two dimensional Character array

Tags: java, arrays, string

I wanted to convert the String array elements into char array

For Example:

```
String str[]={"abc","defl","ghi"};
```

I wanted to store the characters in str array to be stored in char arr[] in different indexes

```
For Ex:
char ch[0][]={'a','b','c'};
     ch[1][]={'d','e','f','l'};
     ch[2][]={'g','h','i'};
```

I wanted to do this dynamically,I am able to split the string to characters ,but not able to store it in this order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
char[][] array = new char[str.length][];
for(int i = 0; i< str.length; i++){
    array[i] = str[i].toCharArray();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 8, you can do

```
char[][] arr = Stream.of(str).map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
char[][] ch = new char[str.length];
for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length ; ++i) {
    ch[i] = str[i].toCharArray();
}
```

Comment: You won by 36 seconds. :P

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize a 2D char array without specifying the length of each of array in the 2D array. By doing this, you'll have a 2D array of null arrays because each array will be of different length, depending on the number of characters in the string. So depending on corresponding element in str, the arrays of the char 2D array will have lengths equal to the length of string in `str` after initializing the arrays. Each string in your string array `str` will represent an array in the 2D char array. Each array in the 2D array will contain the characters of the string. This is how you would achieve this.

```
char[][] charArr = new char[str.length]; //number of arrays in 2d array 
                                         //is length of str array
for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++){ //initializing the arrays in charArr
    charArr[i] = new char[str[i].length()];
}
for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++){ //to store the chars in the 2d array
    for(int j = 0; j < charArr[i].length; j++){
          char[i][j] = str[i].charAt(j);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Java 8:

```
char[][] chars = Stream.of(str).sequential().map(String::toCharArray).toArray(char[][]::new);
```